# Get Parent Item from Oracle Table with Level

Tags: oracle

I have some hierarchical data that is ordered and leveled, but the parent/child relationships are not defined explicitly.

```
ORD     ID     LVL
0       ABC      1
1       DEF      1
2       EFG      2
..      ..       3
..      ..       3
..      ..       2
..      ..       2
..      ..       1
```

What I want to do is calculate the parent ID for each row, like this:

```
ORD     ID     LVL     PARENT
0       ABC      1     ABC
1       DEF      1     DEF
2       EFG      2     DEF
..      HIJ      3     EFG
..      KLM      3     EFG
..      NOP      2     DEF
..      QRS      2     DEF
..      TUV      1     TUV
```

I've been fumbling around with case statements and `LAST_VALUE`, but I'm now resorting to asking here.  I think if I can get the parent ids figured out I can use oracle's hierarchical functions to sum data, but now this is just a flat table to me.

How would I do this?

Edit: here's a better sample of data.  ORD is unique and increasing, but it resets every model.  I think this is what is causing my issue..

```
ORD ID      LVL
0   W7957   01
1   29813   01
2   37830   01
3   42986   01
4   C8746   02
5   V1970   02
6   P7958   03
7   P8500   03
8   V2405   03
9   F3400   03
10  E3366   02
11  M2894   03
12  53928   03
13  22480   03
14  27120   02
15  18159   02
16  T4193   03
17  X7371   03
18  X8257   03
```

Final determination - this works.  I had to use rownum instead of ORD and order by MODEL_NAME and ORD, but the solution worked.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is `ORD` unique and increasing countinuously ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ORD` is unique and is increasing countinuously, for example in this way:

```
select * from table555;

       ORD ID         LVL PAR
---------- --- ---------- ---
         0 ABC          1 ABC
         1 DEF          1 DEF
         2 EFG          2 DEF
         3 HIJ          3 EFG
         4 KLM          3 EFG
         5 NOP          2 DEF
         6 QRS          2 DEF
         7 TUV          1 TUV
```

then on Oracle12c you can use this query:

```
select t.* ,
       nvl( 
            ( select id from table555 t1
             where t1.lvl < t.lvl
               and t1.ord < t.ord
             order by ord desc
             fetch first row only
            ) 
            ,
            id ) As my_par
from table555 t
;

       ORD ID         LVL PAR MY_
---------- --- ---------- --- ---
         0 ABC          1 ABC ABC
         1 DEF          1 DEF DEF
         2 EFG          2 DEF DEF
         3 HIJ          3 EFG EFG
         4 KLM          3 EFG EFG
         5 NOP          2 DEF DEF
         6 QRS          2 DEF DEF
         7 TUV          1 TUV TUV
```

---

On earlier version you can use two subqueries:

```
select  ORD,ID,LVL,PARENT,
        (SELECT id FROM table555 t1
         WHERE t1.ord = t.max_ord
        ) as my_parent
FROM (
        select t.*,
               nvl( 
                    (select max( ord )
                    from table555 t1
                         where t1.lvl < t.lvl
                           and t1.ord < t.ord
                    ),
                    ord
               )as max_ord
        from table555 t
) t
;

       ORD ID         LVL PAR MY_
---------- --- ---------- --- ---
         0 ABC          1 ABC ABC
         1 DEF          1 DEF DEF
         2 EFG          2 DEF DEF
         3 HIJ          3 EFG EFG
         4 KLM          3 EFG EFG
         5 NOP          2 DEF DEF
         6 QRS          2 DEF DEF
         7 TUV          1 TUV TUV
```

Comment: Thanks - this works for the first couple of rows but starts giving some weird answers after about level 3.  `ORD LVL ID PARENT
1 1 7957 7957
2 1 9813 9813
3 1 7830 7830
4 1 2986 2986
5 2 8746 2986
6 2 1970 2986
7 3 7958 1970
8 3 8500 5230
9 3 2405 0359
10 3 3400 8153
11 2 3366 2986
12 3 2894 3366
13 3 3928 6413
14 3 2480 5325
15 2 7120 8518
` - can't do what I want with is small comment block...

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), esspecially sample data to work with without dots `.....`in important columns. As I note in the anwer, this query can work only on assumption that **`ORD` is unique and is increasing countinuously**. Without looking at your table and data, it's hard to diagnose the issue.